# Golang Fiber and Auth0

Tags: go, auth0, go-fiber

I'm new to golang, and have followed this (https://auth0.com/blog/authentication-in-golang/) auth0 guide, for setting up a go rest api.
I'm struggeling with converting to Fiber, and in the same time putting my functions that are being called by routes, out to seperate files.

Currently my main file looks like this:

```
func main() {

r := mux.NewRouter()

r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./views/")))
r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))))

r.Handle("/posts", config.JwtMiddleware.Handler(GetPosts)).Methods("GET")
//r.Handle("/products/{slug}/feedback", jwtMiddleware.Handler(AddFeedbackHandler)).Methods("POST")

// For dev only - Set up CORS so React client can consume our API
corsWrapper := cors.New(cors.Options{
    AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST"},
    AllowedHeaders: []string{"Content-Type", "Origin", "Accept", "*"},
})

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", corsWrapper.Handler(r))
}

var GetPosts= http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
collection, err := config.GetMongoDbCollection(dbName, collectionName)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error")
}else{
    fmt.Println(collection)
    //findOptions := options.Find()
    cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
var posts[]bson.M
    if err = cursor.All(context.Background(), &posts); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(posts)
payload, _ := json.Marshal(posts)
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
w.Write([]byte(payload))
}
})
```

So I would like to convert from: r := mux.NewRouter() to fiber and in the same time move my GetPosts function out in a seperate file. When doing this, I can't seem to continue calling my jwtMiddleware.

I have tried this package: https://github.com/Mechse/fiberauth0 but it seems like its broken. At least I can call protected routes without supplying jwt tokens in my header.

Comment: Hey Mathias, have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply convert 'net/http' style middleware handlers with the provided `adaptor` package(https://github.com/gofiber/adaptor). Note you need to make some changes to the function signature provided by auth0 but this works;

```
// EnsureValidToken is a middleware that will check the validity of our JWT.
func ensureValidToken(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    issuerURL, err := url.Parse("https://" + os.Getenv("AUTH0_DOMAIN") + "/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse the issuer url: %v", err)
    }

    provider := jwks.NewCachingProvider(issuerURL, 5*time.Minute)

    jwtValidator, err := validator.New(
        provider.KeyFunc,
        validator.RS256,
        issuerURL.String(),
        []string{os.Getenv("AUTH0_AUDIENCE")},
        validator.WithCustomClaims(
            func() validator.CustomClaims {
                return &CustomClaims{}
            },
        ),
        validator.WithAllowedClockSkew(time.Minute),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to set up the jwt validator")
    }

    errorHandler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error) {
        log.Printf("Encountered error while validating JWT: %v", err)

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        w.Write([]byte(`{"message":"Failed to validate JWT."}`))
    }

    middleware := jwtmiddleware.New(
        jwtValidator.ValidateToken,
        jwtmiddleware.WithErrorHandler(errorHandler),
    )

    return middleware.CheckJWT(next)

}

var EnsureValidToken = adaptor.HTTPMiddleware(ensureValidToken)


app := fiber.New()
app.Use(EnsureValidToken)
app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("Hello, World!")
    })

app.Listen(":3000")
```